# Calendar and headers go blank when selecting time range

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Fullcalendar v4 - when I select a time range in timeGridWeek, the calendar changes appearance. The grid is visible, but the time bar and header disappear, leaving the only feedback as the small time display within the shaded selection range. Everything returns after I release the mouse/touch. Using jQuery 3.5.1 for some Bootstrap v4 elements.
Has anybody encountered this before?

Comment: This isn't a common or known problem. It sounds like more like some kind of issue with your specific setup. So if you need some help you'll have to show us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. See also [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further guidance on asking a question which is likely to be answerable. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I posted in a hurry  using my phone, and didn't trust the keyboard enough to provide a code snippet. Nevertheless, the fact that you (ADyson, of whose answers I've read dozens) say that this isn't a known problem inclines me to fathom it out by myself. If I discover the issue, which may just be caused by the combination or order of includes, I shall post it here.

Comment: No problem, thanks, and good luck. But if you do need some assistance with figuring it out eventually then please update your question and we will be happy to try and help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, who have believed it? User error!  In my css overrides I had given class 'fc-unselectable' a colo(u)r of '#fff' and this was causing not only the headers and time bar, but also *any* text not within a calendar event to 'disappear'. Naturally I would have tested the effects of this override at the time, so assume that some other change since then had brought about the unwanted behaviour. Now I am wracking my brain to find out why I felt that the white font was necessary in the first place. Must add more detailed comments to my code in future...